# Rails - SSL not working for naked domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a standard SSL from godaddy for my domain teamrla.com. This works perfect for https://www.teamrla.com but not for https://teamrla.com

While IP address of both domains are same, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add this answer for anyone who is having a similar problem. So this is how I resolved this issue.

I moved my DNS to Cloudflare and added an A record for naked domain. This worked for me because later my DNS was being managed on cpanel and it doesn't provide any option to add an ANAME.